# Not able to create instance of interface but an object

Tags: java, android

In java we are not able to create an instance of an interface like this:

```
iJack obj = new iJack();    //iJack is an interface
```

However, I noticed that we can do this:

```
iJack obj;
```

**What is the difference between the two?**

**In addition to that, I noticed that you can nest a class within an interface, how is this useful?** I can not think of a practical purpose for this. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
public interface iJack {
    public abstract class Jack_class {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct Java naming conventions for classes/interfaces (start with capital letter, no underscore, just use CamelCase).

Comment: why this post is tagged to Android??

Comment: Do you have a C/C++ background? Java has only references to objects, it never declares and object on the stack. `iJack obj;` declares an uninitialized reference `obj`, it does *not* instantiate an instance of `iJack` on the stack.

Comment: Nesting a class in an interface is just a lexical scope thing. It's useful if the class has a close association with the methods in the interface. It's basically the same as a `public static` nested class inside another class.

Comment: You should start by reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can not be instantiated. Only classes can. However, you can (and should) use an interface as the type of a variable.

Your line...

`iJack obj;`

...declares a variable of the iJack type, but it does not initialize it.

By the way, you should always use a capital letter at the beginning of an interface name.

Comment: thanxs for the info - but what is the purpose of nesting a class within a interface?

Comment: Don't use it. Almost anyone who reads it is going to get really confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a reference variable whose type is an interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class that implements the interface.

you asking *what is the difference between the two*. first one is wrong. you can't instantiate interface but classes that implement those interfaces. so you can't talk about differences

Reference :[Using an Interface as a Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html)

the uses of nested classes in interface has the same purpose as the uses of nested classes in another class. that is scoping the class to the interface.

Reference :[Nested class inside an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098235/nested-class-inside-an-interface)

Comment: what is the benefit of scoping the class to the interface ?

Comment: **It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place** read the oracle java tutorial first