# java basics regarding interface and inner classes

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I am preparing for OCJP 6.0 exam and I encountered some interesting concepts in Java

1. Why do we define a class inside an interface? what is the use of it? As we cannot instantiate the class it seems like it does not have any use. Similarly I found that interface can be declared inside class which I think can be used as abstract class. What is the use of it exactly?
   Possible duplicate : [inner class within Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400828/inner-class-within-interface)
2. what is the concept behind `int[] o = new int[][]{{1}}[0];` I am having 1D array and RHS has 3 dimensions still the code compiles??

why so???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Number 2**: `int[][]{{1}}` initializes a 2D int array, with one row that has one col that has a value of `1`.  The `[0]` indexes into that 2D array (at row index 0) and returns the `int[]` that was initialized which `o` is assigned to.

It's the same concept as initializing an instance of a class and calling a method on it in the same line, ex:

```
String name = (new SomeClass()).getName();
```

*Note*: You're not forced to save a reference to things when initialized - that's why it looks strange because the reference to the 2D int array is lost.

---

**Number 1**: [Define Class In Interface - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/594789/2459730).  It appears there is plenty of info out there for this question already.